# How to use SVN number in Teamcity email notification template

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have been searching for what I thought would be a simple answer but I can not for the life of me find the answer to my question...

All I want to do is have Teamcity's email notifications include the SVN number in the email title or body. I know the SVN number shows up in the build information but that includes a bunch of build 'stuff' along with it, I simply just want the revision number. I have tried the following with no success:

```
${revision.repositoryVersion.displayVersion}
${buildProject.vcsRoots}
${buildType.vcsRoots}
${buildServer.fullServerVersion}
${buildServer.serverMajorVersion}
${buildServer.serverMinorVersion}
${build.vcs.number}
```

I have also looked in the jetbrains interfaces for 'Build', 'Project', 'Build Type', etc. and have not seen a method that contains the SVN number, only the Teamcity build number which is NOT what I want. Maybe I missed something?

On the surface it seems like this should be so simple (similar to how the teamcity build number is retreived) which is why I don't understand why I cant find an answer. Probably searching for the wrong thing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried getting the SVN number in the build information then parsing it out?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I feel like that could work but it also seems like a lot of unnecessary work. Maybe a last resort kind of thing - I'll look into it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at this link: http://zamboch.blogspot.com/2011/07/howto-pass-build-property-from-teamcity.html

Basically it seems like you can access Teamcity Properties like revision number and build number through the build.buildOwnParameters[] property/(method?). In the [] is where you would put the Teamcity Property that you would like. So for my case I added this line to the email template:

Revision Number: #${build.buildOwnParameters['system.build.vcs.number']}

and it worked!